# shell_exec(),exec() on php is not working

Tags: php, shellexecute

i disabled safe_mode by off value and tried with shell_exec(),exec() both functions on 1and1 dedicated server its not working, even its working in another server.

Comment: You might want to choose some accepted answers. 29% is a bit low.

Comment: Or should i enable anything in the php.ini or httpd.conf? please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those (and any other) functions can be disabled in the php.ini. I do this on my servers often. Perhaps you should ask them if those functions are enabled?

Comment: i have access to php.ini, using ssh , so please tell me what should i enable?

Comment: Search the php.ini file for: 
disable_functions =

Comment: there is nothing, its empty. Please find me the solution.

Comment: do you have shell access on the machine?

Comment: Yes i have full acess to it. Its shared hosting server from 1and1. installed ffmpeg,fms to make streaming. please help me to solve this.

Comment: "there is nothing, its empty. Please find me the solution." - best quote today.